# Searching for only the first value in an array in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

So i am creating a account login system which searches a database for a username (and its relevant password) and, if found, will log the user on.

This is what the csv file currently looks like

['dom', 'enter password']

This is written in one field (on an excel spreadsheet), and was written to the file when the user registered. However when I try to log on, the program will only log on if that is what is entered in the field, when I would like it to log on when dom is entered.

Here is the code which reads the csv file to see if the username/password is found on the file:

```
def Get_Details():
    user_namev2=user_name.get().lower() #Make it so entry box goes red if passwords password is incorrect, and red if username is incorrect/not fault
    user_passwordv2=user_password.get().lower()
    with open ('Accounts.csv', 'r') as Account_file:
        reader = csv.reader(Account_file)
        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                if field == user_namev2:
                    print ("In file")
```

Here is how the username and password get written to the csv file upon registering an account.

```
if re.match(user_password2v2, user_passwordv2):
    print("Passwords do match")
    user_info = []
    user_info.append(user_namev2)
    user_info.append(user_passwordv2)
    with open ('Accounts.csv', 'a') as Account_file:
        writer = csv.writer(Account_file)
        writer.writerow([user_info])
        Bottom()
```

Any ideas on how i can search the csv file so that only a certain part of the string is searched and matched with `user_namev2`

Comment: `for field in row` searches every field in the row. Try to look in specific column(s). E.g. `if row[0] == user_name: print("password is", row[1])`.

Comment: They are written in the same row though . As in its all in the same field on excel. What if I add it to an array and search the array? Not sure how i would do that though

Comment: I think you mean they're all in one _column_?

Comment: I attempted it with row[0]. Still the same issue. Only works if ['dom', 'enter password'] is entered (which is the exact copy of the field written in the spreadsheet/csv file.

Comment: When you used `row[0]`, you removed `for field in row:`, right?

Comment: Yes. This gave me an error message. "list index out of range"

Comment: Would it be easier if i changed how i wrote the values? Maybe have the password in one column and the username in the other?

Comment: Where do ``user_name`` and ``user_password`` come from? Does the csv file *literally*  say ``['dom', 'enter password']`` or is it ``dom,enter_password``?

Comment: Looks like your "csv" file is a mess <g>

Comment: It is literally written on the CSV file like that. The name/password gets written to the csv file when you register an account. Now when logging on, it is meant to search the CSV file to see if the username/password entered is already registered?

Comment: That's not a csv format! That is a literal list of values. Are you trying to extract the first field from this literal?

Comment: Yes i am. Does the issue therefore lie with how the information is being written to the csv file?

Comment: I have updated the post to show the part which writes to the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `user_namev2`is whatever is in the `dom` column and `user_passwordv2` is whatever is in the `enter password` column, I would use regex to a part of the `username` that is in `dom` column.

```
import regex

with open ('Accounts.csv', 'r') as Account_file:
    reader = csv.reader(Account_file)
    for row in reader:
        if re.findall(user_namevv2[0:5],row[0]): #slice a part of the user name 
            print ("In file")
```

Note: I'm also choosing to take the first element of every `row` with `row[0]` since that is the `dom` column.

Comment: In the csv file, there is no dom column. There is just ['dom', 'enter password'] (literally written like that) written in a blank file excel spreadsheet. I am looking to pick apart the first string in that (strings are separated with '). So to explain further, the first value in the '  ' (which in this example is dom) is the username. The second is the password (which in this example is 'enter password'). Sorry if this confused you.

Comment: When i attempt to type that example it gives me the error message "Index Error: list index out of range"

Comment: That's confusing, but Ok. Question: is this an excel or a csv file?