# Writing 2 variables on the same row in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, row, col

I am creating a registering system which (when registered), writes the username and password to a csv file.
How do i get the two variables user`_namev2` and user`_passwordv2` to be written next to eachother on the csv file?

This is the code i am currently using

```
if re.match(user_password2v2, user_passwordv2):
    print("Passwords do match")
    with open ('Accounts.csv', 'a') as Account_file:
        writer = csv.writer(Account_file)
        writer.writerow([user_namev2])
        writer.writerow([user_passwordv2])
        Bottom()
```

This code writes the username and password below eachother, when I would like it to be next to eachother on the same row, just different columns.

I have also experimented with adding it all to an array and writing it the array to the csv file, however this caused troubles when it came to reading the csv file (posted a question about this. See link below)

```
    if re.match(user_password2v2, user_passwordv2):
        print("Passwords do match")
        user_info = []
        user_info.append(user_namev2)
        user_info.append(user_passwordv2)
        with open ('Accounts.csv', 'a') as Account_file:
            writer = csv.writer(Account_file)
            writer.writerow([user_info])
```

[Searching for only the first value in an array in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408463/searching-for-only-the-first-value-in-an-array-in-a-csv-file/52415397?noredirect=1#comment91795768_52415397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that

`writer.writerow([user_namev2, user_passwordv2])`

should do the trick. (https://realpython.com/python-csv/)

Comment: Thanks. do you also know why my program skips a row in the spreadsheet? For some reason it writes the info every other row

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it could have something to do with `Bottom()`? You could also try just using something like `writer.write([user_namev2, user_passwordv2+'\n'])`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using pandas like this

```
import os
import pandas as pd

if re.match(user_password2v2, user_passwordv2):
  print("Passwords do match")
  if os.path.isfile('Accounts.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv('Accounts.csv')
  else:
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['username', 'password'])
  df = df.append({'username': user_namev2, 'password': user_passwordv2})
  df.to_csv('Accounts.csv')
```

This might not be entirely correct (I haven't tested it myself) but you get the idea how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

As Jackson Hill mentioned, you should use list for writerow.

```
if user_passwordv2 == user_password2v2:
    print("Passwords do match")
    with open('Accounts.csv', 'a') as Account_file:
        writer = csv.writer(Account_file)
        writer.writerow([user_namev2, user_passwordv2])
```

Answer (score 0):

"do you also know why my program skips a row in the spreadsheet? For some reason it writes the info every other row"

I had the same problem you need to use `lineterminator = '\n'`, for example

Creating a csv writer object

```
csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, lineterminator = '\n').
```